# Selenium Grid python TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I've set up my selenium grid and I have a hub running on the port 4441 with this command:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub -port 4441

Then I got my node running as well using this command:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4441/grid/register -maxSession 20 -port 5555

That went fine, then I exported my testcase (which I made in the selenium IDE) as a python script, called "test.py" Here is the code for that file...

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class Exec_dashboard_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4441, "*chrome", "http://localhost:8080/rootpage")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_exec_dashboard_test(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/risksense/login")
        sel.type("id=username_or_email", "joeTest")
        sel.type("id=password", "test")
        sel.click("id=loginButton")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.open("/risksense/")
        sel.click("css=div.module-text")
        sel.click("css=#submodule-4 > a")
        time.sleep(6)
        sel.double_click("css=path")
        sel.click("//div[@id='popup']/div/div[2]/button[2]")
        sel.double_click("css=rect.bar")
        sel.click("//div[@id='popup']/div/div[2]/button[2]")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Finally, I attempted to run the python script using this command:

python test.py

I got this error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Anything weird about your environment? python and selenium versions?

Comment: I have the latest versions of both python and selenium server, so that shouldn't be a problem. Does anyone think it could have anything to do with the fact that I'm running it on localhost?

Comment: Also, it works on a virtual machine but now on native Windows 7.